# How to add attributes to form field in template

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to customise the rendering of a form field:

```
{{ form.password1 }}
```

how can I get that to become something like:

```
<input id="signup-password" type="password" class="form-control login-password" placeholder="Password">
```

Note: I don't have control of the form (as it's a form in django allauth)

Comment: Why can't you override the form?

Comment: Check out the package [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for outputting forms for use with bootstrap.

Comment: As per the original post, I don't have control of the form because I'm using django allauth.  Does that mean the only way I can control the attributes on a form field is via the form not via the template? (django crispy forms - thanks I've used that before with bootstrap - I can't control the form here so doesn't help unfortunately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing this via a filter was the easiest option.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='addcss')
def addcss(field, css):
   return field.as_widget(attrs={"class":css})
```

in template:

```
{{field|addcss:"form-control"}}
```

source: http://vanderwijk.info/blog/adding-css-classes-formfields-in-django-templates/